# Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Invalid yaml

Tags: cassandra

I have to modify the source code of Cassandra，but when I debug the cassandraDaemon suggested by https://cassandra.apache.org/_/development/ide.html , I have this strange error:
`

```
Invalid yaml: file:/home/cjx/Downloads/depart0/depart-main/conf/cassandra.yaml
 Error: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;  in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
    ^
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/home/cjx/Downloads/depart0/depart-main/conf/cassandra.yaml
 Error: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;  in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
    ^
19:29:07.494 [main] ERROR o.a.c.service.CassandraDaemon - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/home/cjx/Downloads/depart0/depart-main/conf/cassandra.yaml
 Error: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;  in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
    ^
```

I'm working on centos7(VM) with idea IntelliJ

In fact, I can run cassandra on command line by using ( ./cassandra) . Anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Comment: You mentioned "I have to modify the source code of Cassandra"; what was changed?